# Fluentd removes log entry after applying json parser

Tags: docker, fluentd, stackdriver

I got 2 docker containers using Fluentd as log driver. Both send valid JSON messages. Here are examples of them:

```
{"tag":"docker/article-api","log":"{\"level\":\"debug\",\"port\":\":80\",\"time\":\"2020-02-17T17:06:46Z\",\"message\":\"starting the server\"}"}

{"log":"{\"level\":\"info\",\"ts\":1581959205.461808,\"caller\":\"apiserv/main.go:69\",\"msg\":\"Service is ready to listen\"}","tag":"docker/user-api"}
```

They are quite different, but I am sure both are valid.
As we use Stackdriver logging, I'd like to add the "severity" field equal to the value of level.

Here's the part of the config file, that creates all the confusion.

```
<filter **>
  @type parser
  key_name log
  replace_invalid_sequence true
  <parse>
    @type json
  </parse>
</filter>
```

And here's the problem itself. After passing through the filter, the first log entry message is completely removed, while the second one got passed through.

I've tried to specify time_format, but it doesn't seem to work at all.

Aside from that, I've tried to use `filter docker**`, but it removes all the useful entries instead. It has nothing  to do with it, but if you got an idea on what has caused it, I'll appreciate this

Thank you in advance

P.S. I'm using the google-fluentd service if it does make a difference.